# Как можно сверстать текст на котором фрагмент другого цвета?

Tags: javascript, html, css, шрифты

как можно сверстать текст на котором фрагмент другого цвета как на скрине ниже?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.test {
  font-size: 300px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: bold;
  
  background-color: #bbb;
  
  background-image: radial-gradient(#036 50%, #bbb 50% 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 280px 280px;
  background-position: 30px 60px;
  
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  
  color: white; /* на случай, если браузер не поддерживает clip: text */
}
```

```html
<span class="test">2</span>
```

Comment: Гений, спс большое